# Does 'module.exports' have to be syntactically located inside the file containing the export?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does `module.exports` have to be syntactically located inside the file containing the export?

For example, if I define a global function property `myDefine` that attempts to perform the `module.exports` assignment from inside itself, will this work.

If not, why not?

**file1.js**

```
GLOBAL.myDefine = function(fn) {
  module.exports = fn;
};
```

**file2.js**

```
require('./file1');
myDefine(function() {
  return function MyExport() {};
});
```

Comment: Is your GLOBAL.myDefine an IIFE? where is it being invoked?

Comment: The assignment to `GLOBAL.myDefine` is being performed when the code returned by `require('./file1');` of `file2.js` is evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Node requires file, it wraps the contents in an outer function:

```
function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname){

}
```

When file1.js gets interpreted, the `module.exports = fn` will reference its own local `module` instance, hence it will have no impact on file2.js. In order to get this to work, you'd need to somehow pass file2.js `module` instance to file1's `myDefine()` e.g.

file1.js

```
GLOBAL.myDefine = function(module, fn) {
  module.exports = fn;
}
```

file2.js

```
require('./file1');
myDefine(module, function() {
  return function MyExport() {};
});
```